# what does "Detected an unexpected exception in ~QObject while emitting destroyed()." mean

Tags: qt, destructor

I have a Qt application that crashes with a segmentation fault when an instance of class A is being destroyed and trying to signal destroy() to an instance of class B (which has a slot for destroyed() from A).
While the destruction occurs, just before the crash, I got:

> Detected an unexpected exception in ~QObject while emitting destroyed().,

then, the segfault with the following backtrace:

```
#0  0x0000000000 in ??
#1  0x35b9b0117a in QObject::~QObject() ...
```

What does this mean? what kind of expection do we talk about?. In the destruction process, both A and B could be eventually destroyed, but as I understand signals are disconnected on destruction, so the destruction order should not matter...
What DOES matter then?

Comment: Are you using `void QObject::deleteLater()` ?? which portion of the code deleted the object?

Comment: can you please post the connect() that connects the signal and the slot?

Comment: The code is rather complex and it is more a general question: It is probably me doing an error, but I don't know what CAN go wrong when sending destroyed() signals.
I tried deleting B (the receiver) with both delete and deleteLater.
The connect statement is a normal connect but refers to data internal to the application. It can of course be wrong, but what should I search for?

Comment: and what does the error message sent by Qt really mean? what does Qt react on?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Something threw an exception when `QObject::destroyed()` was called (recall that `emit` is an empty macro). A signal in Qt simply calls `QMetaObject::activate(...)`, and that's what threw the exception. You can inspect that code and try and figure out why the exception was thrown. Probably something somewhere became a dangling or zero pointer in a related QObject instance's data structures. I presume it only happens in release code? Doesn't your debugger trip on it and allow you to figure out what's wrong?